# Retrieve values from sets in dictionary

Tags: python

If I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
dict={1: set(['A','B','C']), 2: set(['D','E'])}
```

How can I retrieve a particular element from a set? For example, retrieving the letter `'A'`. I tried `dict[0][0]` but it does not work! This seems to work only with lists.

Comment: #1) your dict does not have a key `0`.  #2) sets are unordered.

Answer (score 1):

you cannot retrieve a given element: `set`s are not ordered, designed mostly for quick `in` operation (ex: `'A' in dict[1]` returns `True`)

You can use `dict[1].pop()`, that would give you an element from the set under key `1` of `dict` dictionary (note: avoid `dict` as dictionary variable name), and would remove the item from the `set`.

This is often used for job queues: the order of the returned items is unimportant. Only the uniqueness is important.

```
>>> s = {'A','B','C'}
>>> list(s)
['B', 'C', 'A']
>>> s.pop()
'B'
>>> s.pop()
'C'
>>> s.pop()
'A'
```

as you see, there's no way to tell the order with `set`s.

Answer (score 0):

You can say `'A' in mySet` which returns true or false.  You don't seem to need to retrieve anything, shouldn't checking for existence suffice?

You can also iterate over the values of the set.